# Assign smart pointer in condition or loop

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I'm updating some pre c++11 code to use c++11 unique_ptrs.

One thing I'm unsure how to handle is when the old code was using pointer assignment as a condition. E.g.

```
Object* obj;
while ( obj = C_LIBRARY_CALL_WHICH_RETURNS_NEW_OBJECT() )
{
   // do something with obj
   delete obj;
}
```

Given that std::unique_ptr::reset has no return value, it's not possible to translate this directly to:

```
std::unique_ptr< Object > obj;
while ( obj.reset( C_LIBRARY_CALL_WHICH_RETURNS_NEW_OBJECT() ) )
{
   // do something with obj
}
```

So, what's the cleanest way to upgrade this code to use unique_ptrs? The best I can come up with is:

```
std::unique_ptr< Object > obj;
obj.reset(  C_LIBRARY_CALL_WHICH_RETURNS_NEW_OBJECT() );
while ( obj )
{
   // do something with obj
   obj.reset(  C_LIBRARY_CALL_WHICH_RETURNS_NEW_OBJECT() );
}
```

But that adds the messy double call to the library function, which ideally I'd like to avoid.

Comment: If you were using C++17, it allows: `while ( obj.reset( LIBRARY_CALL() ); obj )`

Comment: @aschepler: what now?

Comment: `C_LIBRARY_CALL_WHICH_RETURNS_NEW_OBJECT` which you `delete`? That's suspicious.

Comment: Possibly I simplified the example too much - in reality the unique_ptr is defined with a custom deleter which call's the library's clean up function.

Comment: @KerrekSB http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r1.html, accepted June 2016.

Comment: @aschepler: *selection* statements?! `while`? Hm....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
while ( auto obj = std::unique_ptr<Object>( C_LIBRARY_CALL_WHICH_RETURNS_NEW_OBJECT() ) )
{
   // do something with obj
}
```

Comment: The `while` checks if the `unique_ptr` is null (via its `bool` conversion operator), so there is no need to check if `obj` is null inside the loop body

Comment: You can lose the auto by writing `while (std::unique_ptr<Object> obj{ LIBRARY_CALL_WHICH_RETURNS_NEW_OBJECT() })`.    Note that it must be a C++ library call, not a C library, because the C allocators and C++ new/delete aren't compatible.

Comment: The downside to the answer's approach is that this limits the scope of the pointer, so you can't `break;` out of the while loop and keep using the pointer.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I like the `auto` and the left hand side definition. I really like the concept presented by Herb Sutter in CppCon where he say that type definitions are moving to the right side.

Comment: @BenVoigt I would say that is also the upside - limiting the scope.

Comment: @Galik, the `auto` definition limits `obj` to the exact same scope

Comment: The scope limitation is a plus to me - the original implementation would loop until a nullptr was returned, so any use outside of the loop would be invalid anyway.

Comment: Thanks - this answer seems obvious now!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep `obj` alive outside the loop, you can use the comma operator:

```
std::unique_ptr< Object > obj;
while ( obj.reset(  C_LIBRARY_CALL_WHICH_RETURNS_NEW_OBJECT() ), obj )
{
    // do something with obj
}
```

Comment: I'd never encountered this use of comma before - but in this case it's a very elegant solution!